# Codeium Chat is not accessible in JetBrains IDEs

Tags: intellij-idea, jetbrains-ide, rider

According to the official website and their YouTube videos, Codeium Chat is supposed to be accessible from the JetBrains IDEs. But I have no way of accessing the chat window...

I wanted to know if I'm the only one or if there is a way to correct this? I don't even have the buttons above the functions to explain or generate the doc!

I installed the latest version of PhpStorm, Rider and Android Studio, the latest version of the extension. But in none of the IDEs is the functionality accessible!

Comment: Did you install the corresponding plug-in? https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/20540-codeium-ai-autocomplete-and-chat-for-python-js-ts-java-go-.

Comment: Yes, and I even reinstalled it just in case! But it does not change anything !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally, I found the solution!
JetBrains always used OpenJDK which is installed on my system instead of the jdk/jre made for the JetBrains IDEs!
To change it, simply go to the actions search and search for "Choose boot Java runtime", then choose the JetBrains Runtime with JCEF!
THANKS

Comment: Which one of JetBrains Runtime with JCEF? There is a bunch of them with JCEF!

Comment: I chose the last version and it works.. :-D

Comment: @VítKapitola I am glad to hear you use it but as to me I still have AS crash. I tried different versions of AS and their java runtimes but nothing of that attempts does help.

Comment: @palsega I use version 17.0.8b1000.8-jcef and it's working very well !
I don't tested the latest version 17.0.9bxxxx

Comment: @palsega I use version 17.0.6b653.34 and operating system Ubuntu.

Comment: @VítKapitola ok, thank you for info

Comment: Try 17.0.8 - 17.0.10 did't help((

Comment: I'm using the one bundled by default in Android Studio and that changes nothing.

Answer (score 3):

First you need to install the plugin: https://codeium.com/jetbrains_tutorial

If you press Ctrl+Shift+A you can search for "Codeium Chat", which should give you a chat window that docks to the right.

One problem I've had is that Codeium in Webstorm gives me lovely "Refactor / Explain / Docstring" links above each function but I don't get the same in Rider.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I tried installing codeium and even reinstalling it but it doesn't change anything. When I look I can't find the good option anymore! Besides, I'm on Linux, maybe that's the problem?

Comment: Same problem here with Mac.